# Is which element is deleted defined by std::unique?

Tags: c++11, stl

Based on the [example code here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) I wrote this small example ([ideone Link](https://ideone.com/c8A1d9)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s = "foo123bar456wibble";
    auto end = std::unique(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char l, char r){
        return std::isdigit(l) && std::isdigit(r);
    });
    // What does s hold?
    std::cout << std::string(s.begin(), end) << '\n';
}
```

My output is:

```
foo1bar4wibble
```

Does the standard guarantee this behaviour, or would this also be acceptable?

```
foo2bar6wibble
```

The linked cppreference page says:

> Removing is done by shifting the elements in the range in such a way that elements to be erased are overwritten.

But is that normative text or just a suggested implementation?

Furthermore, [cplusplus.com says](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/):

> Removes all but the first element from every consecutive group of equivalent elements in the range [first,last).

But again is that normative?

Comment: The standard is publicly available, more or less. The behavior of this function isn't exactly hiding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[25.3.9 [alg.unique]/1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf)

> *Effects*: For a nonempty range, eliminates all but the first element from every consecutive group of equivalent elements referred to by the iterator `i` in the range `[first + 1,last)` for which the following
>   conditions hold: `*(i - 1) == *i` or `pred(*(i - 1), *i) != false`.